# View javascript generated by rjs file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The question is simple, yet I didn't find an answer to it yet:

How can I view the javascript code generated by an rjs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among many useful features the [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin can show you AJAX generated requests and responses.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I installed firefox with firebug and it's indeed a very interesting plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Besides FireBug, you may want to look at the [Phoenix Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11708/). It allows viewing and editing of any JS active on a web page.

I wouldn't recommend having Firebug or Phoenix active for day-to-day browsing as it slows down Firefox. Firebug can be switched of, but the Phoenix add on has to be deactivated in the AddOns window.